# TexStudio, MiKTeX and Sumatra; Compilation Issue

Tags: miktex, texstudio, sumatrapdf

All is in place: latest version of TexStudio, latest version of MiKTeX (I chose the installation for my 64x windows 8.1), and latest version of SumatraPDF. I installed every package by hand which TexStudio told me to, using the package manager of MiKTeX, the updater of MiKTeX and refreshed using the Setting option of MiKTeX.
*My problem*: I press F6 to compile my document, TexStudio writes "Process exited normally" but **SumatraPDF doesn't automatically open**. The new document is created but I would like SumatraPDF to open automatically like it usually did.
I also looked through Google, replaced MiKTeX by TeXLive, and reinstalled over and over again. Nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortcut `F6` in TeXstudio is 'Compile', and `F5` is 'Compile and view', or `F1` prior to version 2.12.2. That is, if you press `F5`, TeXstudio will compile the TeX source file and then (if no error occurs) open the PDF viewer. If you want to open the generated PDF file automatically, use `F5` rather than `F6`.

In order to use SumatraPDF as the default PDF viewer, you have to use the external PDF viewer and set it to SumutraPDF. Here is a step-by-step guidance.

1. Options (in the menu bar) -> Configure TeXstudio ... -> The Commands Label
2. Modify the value of `External PDF Viewer` to `"path\to\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -forward-search "?am.tex" @ -fwdsearch-permanent 1 "?am.pdf"`
3. The Build Label
4. Select `External PDF Viewer` for PDF Viewer in Meta Command area.
5. Click `OK` at the bottom of the window

That's it.

Enjoy TeX and [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com). `: )`

Comment: Default shortcuts has changed in current version (2.12.2). Compile and View is now on `F5` key.

Answer (score 4):

If you want both forward and inverse search in one command it can also be done.

1. Options (in the menu bar) -> Configure TeXstudio ... -> Commands (tab on the left)
2. Set "External PDF Viewer" to `"C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/TeXstudio/texstudio.exe\" \"%%f\" -line %%l" -forward-search "?c:am.tex" @ "?am.pdf"`

Remember to change the paths to Sumatra and Texlive.

Sources:
https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/wiki/Command-line-arguments
http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION37

Comment: This works perfectly. But when Sumatra is already open I get the message that the process was terminated with errors. Everything seems to work but the message is displayed every time i recompile my tex.