# Forward-search with several SumatraPDF files opened does not work sometimes

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

**Reproduce:**

- Get Forward-search working
- Have TeXstudio opened
- Have the compiled PDF file opened with SumatraPDF
- Open a second different pdf with SumatraPDF
- Click on it so that this document is in focus
- Go back to TeXstudio
- Do a forward search

**Result**:

New (third) pdf is opened and searched

**Expected:**

Go to already opened file and search there

**Some info which I think may be relevant:**

- It works if the correct window was in focus before changing to TeXstudio and searching
- Command used for forward search: `dde:///"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe":SUMATRA/control/[ForwardSearch("?am.pdf","?c:am.tex",@,0,0,1)]`
- Command to open external PDF viewer: `"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance %.pdf`
- Tabs are off in SumatraPDF
- Windows 7

I also tried the settings proposed here and got the same result:
[TexStudio, MiKTeX and Sumatra; Compilation Issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219629/texstudio-miktex-and-sumatra-compilation-issue)

**Question:**

Is the issue I am experiencing a bug or did I do something wrong? If this is a bug, do I report it to TexStudio or to SumatraPDF?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Sorry, but have you read my the description completely? Especially the part where I referenced another post that basically had the same things set up as your post? Did you even understand that I do *not* need help to set up forward search?

Comment: You could have overlooked my comment or said thanks it is irrelevant instead of this interrogation.